# Error when getting data from coredata?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

I am developing an app that saves a URL using CoreData. I am defining `NSManagedObjectContext`, `NSManagedObjectModel`, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` in `CoreDataRepository`  object class instead of AppDelegate. I am saving this URL using reference of CoreDataRepository. I am using the code below for getting CoreData

```
-(void)getcoredata
 {
  _coredatarep = [[CoreDataRepository alloc] init];

  NSManagedObjectContext *context=[_coredatarep managedObjectContext];
  NSFetchRequest *request=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UrlData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
  [request setEntity:entity];

  NSError *error;
  NSArray *recordsDataArray=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

  urlMutableArray = (NSMutableArray *)recordsDataArray;

  for (int i=0; i<[urlMutableArray count]; i++)
  {
      urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [urlMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]];
       NSLog(@"urlString is %@",urlString);
      _urlLabel.text=urlString;
  }


}
```

In the output, label text shows as

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x9920620> (entity: UrlData; id: 0x991faf0 <x-coredata://A00EB59A-C480-4237-A749-8A40BF908655/UrlData/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in your other thread, it's printing what you told it to print.  `[urlMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]` is a `UrlData` object and that's its description.  If you want a string that's stored inside the `UrlData`, you need to ask it for one of its properties...whatever you've defined them to be in your data model.

Comment: ya thanks for answer i changed that line just now as [urlMutableArray valueForKey:@"url"]; It shows entire data including previous entered data.

Comment: Why don't you try getting the `objectAtIndex:0` (if that's the entity you want) and print one of its properties?  Since you don't show how the entities are defined or how you store things in them, it's not easy to guess **which** property.